# How to navigate an Activity or Fragment on voice input in android

Tags: android

I did google to navigate from one screen to another screen by voice input, either using the Fragment or Activity but i din't get any solution.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

For taking voice input you must be starting an intent.You might be getting result in activity onActivityResult() method.

From there you can start a new activity and you can replace a fragment also.

Comment: Hi, for voice input need to use any library?